# Android MediaPlayer NullPointerException when start method calls

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

My app is a quiz. MediaPlayer instance mp is working and playing a sound and the user guess the sound and touch the screen from 4 imageviews. I tested this app on my phone and my friend's phone and there was not any problem, I published the app. However my problem is, I am getting NullPointerException from several devices when mp.start(); line is called. I know that mp.start() command can throw this exception some times and I added a null checking for mp object, but problem is not solved. My code:

```
public void Question1()
    {
        txtQuizNo.setText("1");
        stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(SoundQuiz.this, R.raw.kopru);
                mp.start();

        Secenek1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baska);
        Secenek2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kopru);
        Secenek3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.neden);
        Secenek4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hepsi);
    }

    public void Question2()
    {
        txtQuizNo.setText("2");
        stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(SoundQuiz.this, R.raw.yol);
                mp.start();

        Secenek1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hani);
        Secenek2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mani);
        Secenek3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yol);
        Secenek4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kral);
    }

    public void Question3()
    {
        txtQuizNo.setText("3");
        stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(SoundQuiz.this, R.raw.baca);
                mp.start();

        Secenek1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tren);
        Secenek2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arac);
        Secenek3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kacak);
        Secenek4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baca);
    }


    private void stopPlaying() {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
```

When I call Question1 or Question2 etc. methods, some devices throw NullPointerException. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: how big are the sound files? and whats the android version running on those devices?

Comment: sound files are 100kb-400kb. android versions are: 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.2 and 4.3.